# is there a was to trigger $.ajaxStart for a single request and not all the requests?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page where I do multiple/different `$.ajax` and `$.getJSON` calls.

on one of the calls I need to show a loading page until the results are loaded on the page.

to display the loading page here is what I have done

```
$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
    $('#output').html('');
    $('#loading').addClass('loading').show();
});
```

and this display the loading page as expected when any `$.ajax` is called.

I have added `global: false` to the the calls where I don't to ignore the `$.ajaxStart` but it is not working.

What can I do to only trigger the `$.ajaxStart` on a single `$.ajax` request?

Comment: Set a global var that has a special value only for the desired `ajax` call, and test for that variable in the `ajaxStart` fn

Comment: Use the `beforeSend:` option of `$.ajax`.